# yocto - create a meta layer with a bbappend file adding dts flle to raspberry pi kernel

Tags: raspberry-pi, kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree

I'm working with *Yocto Kirkstone*. My goal is to add a dts file to the raspberry pi linux kernel. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37366507/11287083) answer and ended up with a new meta-layer and this directory tree:

```
meta-main-layer
meta-raspberrypi
meta-mydts/
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── linux-raspberrypi
        │   └── raspberrypi4-64
        │       └── my.dts
        └── linux-raspberrypi_5.15.bbappend
```

and the *linux-raspberrypi_5.15.bbappend*:

```
SRC_URI += "file://mydts.dts;subdir=git/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays"

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
KERNEL_DEVICETREE += "mydst.dtb"
```

`meta-main-layer` is the layer with image definition, it does include the `meta-mydts` with

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append += " mydts"
```

but for some reason `yocto` complains saying that there's no target `mydts` as below:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'mydts' (but meta-main-layer/recipes-core/images/image-64.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'mydts' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['mydts']
```

How can a meta-layer with linux kernel patches be turned into something that is buildable? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read Yocto documentation [RPROVIDE](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=rprovide).

Basically you want Bitbake to recognize your meta-layer.
`IMAGE_INSTALL:append` is needed when you want to deploy a package in your final target. For example you have `SRC_URI += "helloword.c"` in  `my_helloword.bb` then
`IMAGE_INSTALL:append = my_helloworld` will add your binary `helloword.o` in final target.

Now you can understand trying to `IMAGE_INSTALL:append` a whole meta-layer is nonsense.

The proper way to make your meta-layer "discoverable" by bitbake is to go in your build directory, add in your `conf/bblayers.conf` file the path of your meta-layer in the variable `BBLAYERS`.

Also note that there is a syntax error in `KERNEL_DEVICETREE += "mydst.dtb"`
It should be `KERNEL_DEVICETREE += "mydts.dtb"`

Comment: Does it mean that adding the path to the *meta-mydts* to *conf/bblayers.conf* is enough for raspberry pi kernel to notice the *meta-mydts/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_5.15.bbappend* file and apply it? Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: yes it is enough

Comment: Do you know why could it be, that with my custom `mydts.dtbo` built added to the image, no other `*.dtbo` files are built? And I need these other `*.dtbo`'s as they are essential to the system.

Comment: Okay, I tried many configurations and ended up adding `KERNEL_DEVICETREE:append = " mydts.dtbo" to `layer.conf` only. `+=` operator overwrites the original contents of the `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` variable as it uses weak value operator internally. That ment deleting all other `dtbo` files from the variable, breaking the image completely.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem and decided to post the steps here. This is based on @void_brain answer and [@bvarner post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316530/11287083). Below instructions are up to date with *Yocto Kirkstone 4.01*.

The **.dts* file name has to include `-overlay.dts` suffix, every raspberry pi dt-overlay file has to follow that convention (step 2). Keep in mind, that the *Device Tree Blob* or **.dtbo* file can not include this suffix anymore (step 3).

To add a custom **-overlay.dts* file, follow below steps:

1. First, get into the environment of the yocto project with `source poky/oe-init-build-env` to get access to the `bitbake` command. Later create a new layer for the **overlay-dts* file:

   ```
   $ bitbake-layers create-layer meta-mydts
   ```
2. Import the **-overlay.dts* file to the freshly created meta-layer with `recipetool` command. It will create *recipes-kernel/linux* directories with a *linux-raspberrypi_%.bbappend* file. If your **-overlay.dts* file is made for a specific machine, for example `raspberrypi4-64`, include it's name with the `-wm` parameter.

   ```
   recipetool appendsrcfile -wm raspberrypi4-64 . virtual/kernel path/to/mydts-overlay.dts 'arch/${ARCH}/boot/dts/overlays/mydts-overlay.dts'
   ```
3. Add `KERNEL_DEVICETREE:append = " overlays/mydts.dtbo"` without the `-overlay` suffix to **.conf* file, that can be *meta-mydts/conf/layer.conf*. This will tell *Yocto* to build your **-overlay.dts* file into a **.dtbo* and include it in the image.
4. Include the path to `meta-mydts` layer in *build/conf/bblayers.conf*, to make the layer discoverable for *Yocto*.

That's about it. For automatic activation of the overlay look into the [@bvarner post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316530/11287083) post.

Edit:

The overlay activation mechanism that worked the best for me is with the use of `RPI_EXTRA_CONFIG` variable. This variable should be put in the `build/conf/local.conf`, as below:

```
RPI_EXTRA_CONFIG:append = "\ndtoverlay=mydts\n"
```

The other location is `layer.conf` of the layer of your project that has a recipe for the image.